# Background Audio stops on navigating to different Views in a SwiftUI app?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to play a background sound in SwiftUI.

I can play the sound like this:

```
var aplayer = AVPlayer()
```

And

```
onAppear {

let aplayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3")!)
            aplayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: aplayerItem)
            aplayer.play()

    }
```

But the above code has issues.

1- it only loops for a short period of time.

2- If I navigate between my Views, the sound will stop. I know this is happening because my code is inside the `.onAppear {...}`. But How do I make it accessible and keep on playing even if the Views being changed?

Comment: Don't put `AVPlayer` in view property - it can be recreated, do this instead in view model (or helper), ie. outside of view. In view only activate that via some function call.